# Bash: How do I show the name of a specific java -jar in Top command?

Tags: bash, top-command

***Note:*** this is not a java question. I'm asking about the Top Command in bash.

Often I am running several programs written in java at the same time. For example;

```
`java -jar [program] [options]`
```

I want to check that they are running using `top`, however when I try it the output says java is running.

[image]

Is there a way to get the last column to say the program's name instead of "*java*"?

Comment: Note that in general, questions about *using UNIX tools*, as opposed to questions about writing code, are a better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I didn't realise these two forums existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`top -c` will show you the command details, but with java programs it might be too long to be useful.

Comment: Works great, thanks. While the command details are very long, I got the information I wanted from it.